# Programmatically write Excel on Office 365

Tags: c#, excel, office365

I'd like to write excel file on Office 365 by window application using VS 2005.
which service or API required for the same.

Comment: If you search here you will find some.

Comment: See the related links on the right side of this page. See the question that has 636+ votes up? That is your answer.

Comment: This link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: I have checked this link,Export Excel using EPPplus/open office and Msoffice. I am already exporting data using EPPplus and MS Office 2010. But How do I relate this with Office 365. Save and access files virtually at shared place.

Comment: oho, in my post i mentioned office 2005 . now corrected [ I need to export excel using Office 365'

Comment: @Elliana, are you referring to creating/editing an online Office 365 spreadsheet as opposed to a desktop spreadsheet? I suspect so.

Comment: Excel Services REST API  ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [Office OpenXml library](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) , I used it and it has a good reputation.